# how to intergrate Sap crytal report to .net installer using C#

Tags: asp.net, windows, crystal-reports, installation

I have an installer and i want to add Sap Crystal Report to this installer. Can we do this, If yes, Please let me know how? I am in big trouble please help me.

Comment: have you gotten what you need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is difficult in that.

1. In MSI installer open the Application Folder.
2. select Add new file option.
3. Select all crystal reports as you used in your application.
4. Report location is as same as your application. Means if you put the crystal report in folder then same folder you need to create the Application folder.
5. If you use the xml,xsd file for support then please verify they have full rights read -write access permission into ApplicationDirectory after Installation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Web setup project. You can add Prequisities called [Bootstrapper Manifest packs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx) to your VS2010 using a very good tool which is Bootstrapper Manifest Generator. [here is a good tutorial how to build custom prerequisities](http://ntsblog.homedev.com.au/index.php/2011/03/03/bootstrap-manifest-generator-2008-how-to-guide-v2/) , then you add them into Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages folder (v7.0A case windows 7 or 2008) 
Hope it helps